# jQuery mouseleave trigger on every pixel, when flash movie is below div

Tags: jquery, flash, hover, mouseleave

I have a problem with a flash movie, that is initated below a div element with `z-index: 2000;`. I have a `onMouseDown` event, on the div - which is triggering fine, and I have `$(divelement).hover(functionIn(),functionOut())` attached. (The `onClick` event is captured by the underlying flash regardless of z-index)

In FF and IE9 this is all working as expected, but in IE8 the functionOut() and functionIn() is triggered on every pixel! What's a good way to fix this?

Possible to add some sort of pixel boundaries based on the element size and position to aid .hover() ?

Comment: In a previous project, one of my colleagues successfully captured mousedown event with a transparent div over a flash content.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of your problem, but you might try tinkering with the wmode property of your swf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this now. By using a 1px transparent gif as background on the overlaying div, the mouseleave isn't triggered until it actually should be :)